# how to force symfony to create service instance eagerly instead of creating when it is access first time (lazily)?

Tags: php, symfony

Below is my service definition

```
    <service id="st_mongo.mongo_config" class="St\Common\MongoBundle\Mongo\StMongoConfig"
             factory-class="St\Common\MongoBundle\Mongo\StMongoConfig"
             factory-method="factory" public="false">
        <argument>%mongo_dsn%</argument>
        <argument>%mongo_db_collection_map%</argument>
    </service>
```

Symfony creates instance of this service (it calls factory-method "factory") when the service is accessed first time by using

```
$continer->get("st_mongo.mongo_config");
```

I want, service instance should be created when symfony is bootstraped. I shouldnt need to call above service manually.

Is there any way to forcefully tell symfony to create service instance eagerly at the time of boostraping instead of creating lazily when called first time ?

May be I can use kernel events but there are no events common to http and console.

**Update**:
I could make it work using http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html#execute-code-during-compilation -- but not sure how reliable is it. -- This didn't work as it won't be called once cache is created.

Comment: You can hook commands into the listener system with: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/events.html and just use the same listener for commands as well as http.  But you should really make sure you want the behavior.  I suspect you are trying to do something in the constructor that you always want to run?  Might be a better approach.

Comment: If this is very basic stuff, you could simply implement `\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\BundleInterface::boot` in your `AppBundle` (if that's the name of the bundle in question).

Comment: @Yoshi Thanks it worked perfectly !

Comment: @vishal Perfect! You might want to add an answer explaining what you did, and what your use-case was. This might be helpful to future visitors.